# Deriving Formula for Marginal Distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, continuous-data

I'm having trouble understanding exactly why when you have a two-dimensional random variable $(X,Y)$ and you want to find the marginal probability distribution of $X$, for example, you integrate the joint probability density function with respect to ***y***. That is,

$f_x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y) \ dy$

I understand its analogous form in the discrete case:

$p(X=x_i)=\sum_j p(x_i,y_j)$

because here you're just adding up the different ways $X$ can be $x_i$ (i.e., it can be $x_i$ when $Y$ is $y_1$ or $y_2$ etc.) but I don't get exactly what is being done by integrating with respect to $y$. What is being summed up? And how does it work when there are no distinct probabilities but only a probability density, in terms of adding up possibilities to "marginalize out" a variable?

Answer (score 3):

The joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is defined in terms of probability as
$$\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in A)=\int_A f_{XY}(x,y)\,\text{d}x\text{d}y$$ for all *measurable* sets $A$. When $A$ is of the special form $A=[a,b]\times[c,d]$, this translates as
$$\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in A)=\int_c^d\int_a^b f_{XY}(x,y)\,\text{d}x\text{d}y=\int_c^d\left\{\int_a^b f_{XY}(x,y)\,\text{d}x\right\}\text{d}y$$that is, as the integral in $y$ of a function of $y$ defined as$$g(y)=\int_a^b f_{XY}(x,y)\,\text{d}x$$In particular, when $a=-\infty$ and $b=+\infty$ you get that$$\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in \mathbb{R}\times[c,d])=\int_c^d\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)\,\text{d}x\text{d}y$$which shows that$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)\,\text{d}x$$operates like a density for $Y$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the integral in terms of Riemann sums...could you help me out with that

Comment: @Gabriel, probability integrals do not always work with riemannian definition of an integral. If you still want to cast them as Riemannian, then imagine that x and y are cut into bins. In this case the integrals become sums.

Comment: There is not much difference with Riemann sums when $f$ is continuous or continuous by parts and when $A$ is a union or intersection of a collection of cubes $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, which is why I wrote this explanation for a single cube.

Comment: So then how would I interpret $\sum f(x,y) \Delta y $

Comment: I do not understand what this sum means in terms of the original problem.

Comment: Meaning if you rewrite the double integral as the limit of a double sum, what does the inner sum represent?

Comment: The inner integral can be seen as$$\lim_{\Delta_x\to 0} \sum_x f(x,y)\Delta_x$$i.e., as a regular Riemann integral when $f$ is regular enough.

Comment: @Xi'an but what's its interpretation in terms of probability?